# Converters between com.vividsolutions.jts and org.locationtech.jts

Tags: java, jts

jts have changed their package name from `com.vividsolutions.jts` to `org.locationtech.jts` according to their [migration README](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/MIGRATION.md).
I have a library that uses old version of jts and I want to support the new one as well.

I want to be able to convert from old type to new type, but I don't see an easy way to do it. For some types, such as `Coordinate`, its easy to create a manual converter, but for others it is more complicated. Also, there are a lot of type so manually doing this is time consuming.

Is there any automatic way or a library to perform such conversions?

Edit:
Adding a code example for a function I would like to have (true for all other types)

```
 com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.PrecisionModel convertPrecisionModel(org.locationtech.jts.geom.PrecisionModel pm)
```

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, that was not my intention in the question. I added an example in the question body.

Comment: This sounds a bit like an XY problem. Why do you want to convert a org.locationtech.jts.geom.PrecisionModel to a com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.PrecisionModel Usually when you migrate to a newer library, you don't need to migrate all of the types, you just fix your code to use the new type.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit brute force, but you can invoke the toString() method on the old object to get the string representation and use WKTReader from the new JTS to get the geometry from this string

```java
new WKTReader(geometryFactory).read(aWktString)
```